# Unity Gain Buffer Output Impedance

Tags: audio

First time here.  I'm not an engineer so please pardon my lack of technical expertise.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Here's is the circuit in question:

[image]

I've been told that R5 (10K) sets the output impedance of the buffer.  However, there are two other resistors connected to ground when the buffer is connected to a tube amplifier.

Question 1:  Wouldn't the output impedance be set by the 25K pot and the 10K R5 in parallel (7.15K)?
Question 2:  Would it be a better design to put R5 before C3 to set the output impedance at 10K?

Comment: You must attribute the source of the picture with a link (preferably)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I've been told that R5 (10K) sets the output impedance of the buffer.*

The only indication in your schematic of where the buffer output is here: -

[image]

And, that node could be described as the output of the buffer hence, R5 (10 kΩ) plays a role but, the impedance at that node is mainly determined by R4 (100 Ω) and C3 (2.2 μF).

> *Question 1: Wouldn't the output impedance be set by the 25K pot and
> the 10K R5 in parallel (7.15K)?*

Your question seems to assume that the output node of the buffer is at some other point than the node marked "OUT" so, I have to disagree.

> *Question 2: Would it be a better design to put R5 before C3 to set the
> output impedance at 10K?*

R5 is there to stop a DC voltage accumulating on the "OUT" node when nothing is connected hence **it must** be placed where it is.

Comment: Great answer.  Sorry for the lack of clarity.  The buffer is fed by the guitar's pickups at the In node.  The Out node of the buffer is conected directly to the Volume pot of the guitar.  The dashed line represents a guitar cable, so the volume pot is connected to the input of the amplifier thru the cable.

Comment: @Scoid if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

R5 being 10k does not define the output impedance, in fact it has least contribution to it. The volume pot setting will control the output impedance and audio signals come anyway through a 100 ohm  resistor R4 to the pot, so effectively the R5 does very little, so it can be ignored. The capacitor C3 is also relatively large so that it is only a 3.6k impedance at 20 Hz.

1. No, not really. There's three resistors and a capacitor. The capacitor also makes the impedance frequency-dependent, but can be assumed zero for audio frequencies. The impedance is set by all of them if we assume op-amp is ideal and has zero output impedance. And the output impedance mostly depends on the setting of the 25k pot. If you imagine you turn down the volume pot so that there is 25k to signal and 0 ohms to ground, the output impedance is 0. If you turn the pot to mid level, you have 12.5k from output to both ends of the pot, so output impedance is 6.25k if the pot is driven directly with op-amp and no other resistors.
2. No, not really. It depends what would be the purpose of moving it, but as it does not directly define the output impedance anyway, and would result exactly same impedance (assuming cap impedance is ignored as usual with small signal models), it would just add a constant DC load to the op-amp, but other than that, it makes no difference in regards to setting the output impedance.

Comment: Great answer.  Thank you!  One thing I don't understand.  Doesn't the 25K pot always present a 25K path to ground to the buffer regardless of the pot setting?  IOWs, why does the pot setting make a difference in the output impedance?

Comment: @Scoid No, let me explain again, if pot is turned all the way down, there is 0 ohms between output to tube grid and ground, so the output impedance is zero because it is short circuited to ground. The 25k pot has 25k between the two ends of it, regardless of wiper setting.